# How set function on react-navigation navigationOptions?

Tags: javascript, react-native

after setup a simple textInput on navigationOptions, i'd like to render a clear button conditionally.

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const q = navigation.getParam("q", "");
    const onSearch = navigation.getParam("onSearch");
    const onFocus = navigation.getParam("onFocus");

    return {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#fff"
      },
      header: (
        <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
          <HeaderBackButton
            tintColor="black"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")}
          />
          <TextInput
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            style={styles.inputContainer}
            placeholder="Search"
            value={q}
            onChangeText={text => onSearch(text)}
            onFocus={onFocus}
            //clearButtonMode="always"
          />
          {this.renderClearButton()}
        </View>
      )
    };
  };
```

So here is the function

```
 renderClearButton() {
    if (this.state.onSearchStatus == "touched") {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigation.getParam("clearText")}>
          <Image
            style={styles.button}
            source={require("../assets/icons/clear.png")}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }
```

But this happen

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating
>   '_this2.renderClearButton()')

i've tried to:

```
const renderClearButton = navigation.getParam("renderClearButton");
and {renderClearButton}
```

but

> the error now is Functions are not valid as a react child. this may
>   happen if you return a component instead

So is possible to add a function to **navigationOptions**?

Answer (score 1):

In `navigationOption` you do not have access to `this` context, you can not call your method in `navigationOption`.

So now, to dynamically change the header contents,

You can pass one navigation param to your current screen from previous screen like `onSearchStatus`.

use a ternary operator to show your content dynamically like this in `navigationOption` itself,

```
{navigation.state.params.onSearchStatus == "touched" && navigation.state.params.onSearchStatus != undefined  ?
    ....//your touchableopacity code
: null}
```

now to change the content dynamically set params from navigation using `setParams()`,

for [more detail](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1274#issuecomment-299170607),

Comment: Jaydeep thank for the help, but after place {navigation.state.params.onSearchStatus == "touched" ?

and setParams()

Shows: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.state.params.onSearchStatus')

Comment: on Component lifecycle

componentDidMount() {

    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      onSearch: this.onSearch,
      onFocus: this.onFocus,
      clearText: this._clearText,
      onSearchStatus: this.onSearchStatus
    });
  }

Comment: Jaydeep, thank you for your help, but the error still. maybe because the static navigationOptions in on the searchScreen and not on router?

Comment: Jaydeep ok, adding the navigation.state.params && before, stoped the undefined issue, but did not return the button either